# Selection of Dropdown-Item does not work

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the following code, oriented at the ReactBootstrap Components DropdownButton and MenueItem:

```
class Dropdown extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class DropdownItem extends Component {
  handleClick(event) {
    if (this.props.disabled) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    }
    if (this.props.onSelect) {
      this.props.onSelect(event, this.props.eventKey);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
<Dropdown onSelect={this.handleOnSelect}>
    <DropdownItem eventKey="categorize"><i className="icon fa fa-filter"></i>Fotos kategorisieren</DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem eventKey="share"><i className="icon fa fa-link"></i>Fotos freigeben</DropdownItem>
</Dropdown>
```

My problem: DropdownItem does not know this.props.onSelect and so it is not calling my onSelect at Dropdown component. The select does not work.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DropdownItems can automatically inherit from Dropdown props by adding this on Dropdown component

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {...this.props})}
```

or specify only the wanted props

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {onSelect: this.props.onSelect})}
```

**edit** for multiple children elements

```
{React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => React.cloneElement(child, {onSelect: this.props.onSelect}))}
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thx for your answer.

You mean like this, right?

class Dropdown extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { onSelect: this.props.onSelect })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

But so, I become the following error:

"Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined."

Comment: My bad, It works for 1 not for many child, I updated the solution

Comment: Yes thats right :-) I just found it out. Postet it at answer. Thanks a lot Michael :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try passing in the handleOnSelect function as a prop to DropdownItem as well? Something like

```
<Dropdown onSelect={this.handleOnSelect}>
  <DropdownItem eventKey="categorize" onSelect={this.handleOnSelect}><i className="icon fa fa-filter"></i>Fotos kategorisieren</DropdownItem>
  <DropdownItem eventKey="share" onSelect={this.handleOnSelect}><i className="icon fa fa-link"></i>Fotos freigeben</DropdownItem>
</Dropdown>
```

I think you might be confused and think you can only pass props to the top level rendered component, but you can in fact pass them anywhere within the JSX that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have it. The following works:

```
{React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
  return React.cloneElement(child, { onSelect: this.props.onSelect })
})}
```

Thank you @MichaelRasoahaingo for your help!

Comment: Bad realisation, because it will fail in some cases. When you pass only one child, ot did not pass any child, it is not array and you will get map is not a function

Comment: check this https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html 
React.Children.map

Comment: You're welcome don't forget to mark your issue as resolved :)

Comment: good point @degr! thank you! i will make a solution for all cases and post it here. can be tomorrow, because i first have to do another thing.